Web Socket API - does not work when adding a variable
I have the following problem:
When I create topics as follows:
/notifications/room1
Rutime
URl Mapping: /notifications?identifier=room1
it works fine and correctly.
But when I create it as a variable:
/notifications/{roomID}
Rutime
URl Mapping: /notifications?identifier={uri.var.roomID}
the webSocket implementation doesn't work anymore, the problem is when using the field as a variable.

For some reason, and it seems that the problem was to use capital letters, when creating it this way:
/notifications/{roomid}
/notifications?identifier={uri.var.roomid}
It was solved
